# Using Google Analytics Global Site Tag in PHP file rather than HTML

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am trying to implement google analytics to a website composed of PHP files rather than HTML. Can I still use the Global Site Tag simply by adding a head element and pasting the code into the PHP file or do I need to take an alternative route in adding google analytics tracking to this site?

Comment: PHP just outputs HTML. Put it wherever your header is.

Comment: As I remember Google has Good documentation on how to install it. I recommend creating a new PHP file with the GA code and including it in the other pages. That way if you need to change something it's only at one location.

Answer (score 2):

**Create ga_include.php**

Paste your gtag into this file example:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxx-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1');
</script>
```

Include this into the head section of the page you'd like to render, either in a common "head.php" or just "mypage.php" example:

```
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
<?php include_once("ga_include.php") ?>
</head>
```

Modify the path of ga_include.php to the appropriate path if it is not in the same location.